# Who should Gentiles worship?

Tags: gentiles

Forgive me if this question seems inappropriate or ignorant. I mean it as a legitimate question for Jewish people asked by a non-Jewish person.

I was raised in a Christian household. And was always taught that Jesus was  the Messiah not just the Jewish people, but all people.

Now most modern Jews do not accept the legitimacy of Jesus's claim to be Messiah, that being the case, the Deity of Judaism has never (to my knowledge) revealed any path to salvation for gentiles.

So from a Jewish perspective who then should we gentiles worship?

Judaism being  a mostly non proselytizing faith one would assume that the Jewish God does not encourage his followers to spread their faith to the gentile community.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501). Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 5):

The question is neither inappropriate nor ignorant, and thanks for asking it so respectfully.

Judaism believes in one God. One of Judaism's most important statement of faith, called the Shema ([Deuteronomy 6:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.6.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), says

> Hear, O Israel! The Lord is our God, the Lord is one.

**This one God is the one Gentiles should worship.**

---

Judaism does have commandments for non-Jews. They are called the [seven laws of Bnei Noach](http://www.aish.com/atr/Seven_Laws_of_Noah.html) (the sons of Noach, i.e., all of humanity), one of which is

> Do not worship false Gods.

Maimonides (the Rambam, one of the most important codifiers of Jewish law) writes clearly ([Hilchot Melachim 8:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.8.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that any Gentile who observes these seven laws has a portion in the World to Come (which, I believe, is you are calling a path to salvation)

> Anyone who accepts upon himself and carefully observes the Seven
>   Commandments is of the Righteous of the Nations of the World and has a
>   portion in the World to Come.

The reason Judaism does not proselytise (i.e., actively try and convert others) is that we believe that Judaism is for Jews, and the seven laws of Bnei Noach are for non-Jews. As such there is no need to try and convince non-Jews to follow Judaism when they can instead follow the path God carved out for them.

Comment: "does not proselytise" could you please clear that out? What about conversion to Judiasm? גיור , giyur?

Comment: @user4762 proselytism is to try and convince people to convert to a religion or belief. Judaism doesn't do this. It turns away converts initially

Comment: I agree, but it's good to add this so that it's clear what you meant.

Comment: Not seeking out converts is not the same as refusing them. Judaism accepts sincere converts, but only ones that approach Judaism on their own initiative - Jewish missionaries won't come to your door like some other religions do.